# Logstash Docker image configuration

Tags: logging, logstash-configuration

I am new to docker and logstash, i am having issue with configuration of Logstash Docker.

1) I downloaded Logstash docker image 6.0.1 form elasticsearch [will use as base image], i want to use only logstash, will save output log to a file

2) Want to collect logs on same machine, in which logstash will run

3) What configuration should i change or add to docker image [for ex. logstash.conf, logstash.yml]

4) Where should i keep these configuration file.

5) What should be the command to run docker image with configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is plenty of documentation available on elastic site that will help you get started and run a fully functioning logstash setup. Reproducing the instructions etc here does not make sense so I am posting some links that will get you going and answer all your queries above.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/docker-config.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/configuration-file-structure.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/config-examples.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/config-setting-files.html

If you run into any specific issues or have any specific questions which are not answered by the documentation or any existing stack overflow answers please post a new question and we will try to help you :)

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ben5556 i used Dockerfile configuration, Now i am little bit familiar to docker concept... Thanks